# How to send JSON data using POST method swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

How to send JSON data using POST method to server in SWIFT

For Objective C i use this

```
NSMutableDictionary *get = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[get setObject:validEmailTF.text forKey:@"email"];
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:get options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *jsonInputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"r=%@",jsonInputString];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",forgetPasswordUrl]];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:120.0];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (responseData != nil)
{
    jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Values =======%@",jsonDict);
}
```

Convert this code in Swift language. 
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, may be it will help you

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "Your forgetPasswordUrl")!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let params = ["email":validEmailTF.text] as Dictionary<String, String>

request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    print("Response: \(response)")})

task.resume()
```

Comment: pass the keys in the `Dictionary` like this `let params = ["key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"] as Dictionary<String, String>`

Comment: What about one of it contains another array of Dict?

`Like : ["key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":["key11":"val11","key12":"val12","key13":"val13"]]`

Comment: @iUser use `Dictionary<String, Any>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply converted your code to swift without tuning your code.

Try this:

```
    var get: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    get["email"] = validEmailTF.text
    var jsonData: NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(get, options: kNilOptions, error: nil)
    var jsonInputString: String = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var post: String = NSString(format: "r=%@",jsonInputString)

    var get: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(forgetPasswordUrl)")
    var postData: NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    var postLength: String = "\(postData.length())"
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest.requestWithURL(url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 120.0)
    request.URL = url
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = postData

    var error: NSError
    var response: NSURLResponse
    var responseData: NSData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
    if responseData != nil {
        jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: kNilOptions, error: &error)
        print("Values =======\(jsonDict)")
```

Comment: i think you a re using it in object c class. Create a class with swift and try

Comment: No, I am using Swift class

Comment: It works for me. without any error. screenshot added

Comment: I also uploadedt the image

Comment: What can i do ?? @Rajatp